# Calling a Visualforce page with a Custom button on a related list

Tags: visualforce, custom-button

I want to call a visualforce page from a custom button. This button will be on a related list. Currently the button displays but will not launch. Here's the current code that I have.

```
windows.open('/apex/MedaBDPassessment',blank)?
```

But I believe I need to add some of this code below. This visualforce page needs to relate to a record type and case record.

```
/a03/e?RecordType=012i0000000eigY& 
cancelURL={!URLFOR($Action.Case_Record__c.View, Case_Record__c.Id)}& 
CF00Ni0000003WnaZ={!Case_Record__c.Name}& 
CF00Ni0000003WnaZ_lkid={!Case_Record__c.Id}
```

Comment: What's your actual question?

Comment: More importantly, what's the workflow you want to have?

Answer (score 1):

- Make the Custom button list type and select visualforce page  in the Content Source.

  - use standard controller in the vf page to include it in the content field.

Comment: I'm unclear of your second point. I'm currently using the standard controller but I'm not sure what you mean by "include it in the content field"

Comment: Also the name of my button is "Business_Status_Assessment". I appreciate the help. We are a non-profit and we don't have regular access to a developer.

Comment: 'include it in the content field'  when you edit your button there is a field at last named as content .It only comes up if you select visualforce in the content source. The content field show the name of the visualforce page which includes the standard controller for this object.There you have to select the page you want to open up on the button click.